# ASP .NET Core using InMemory Cache per user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a system where at some point, the user will be locked to a single page. In this situation his account his locked and he cannot be redirected to any other page and this is after authentication.

The verification is done using Page Filters accessing database. To improve performance I have used memory cache.

However, the result wasn't as expected because once the cache is used for a single user it will affect all the others.

As far as i know, you can separate caching using tag helpers per user but I have no idea if this is possible using code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Iniciar(int paragemId, string paragem)
{
    var registoId = Convert.ToInt32(User.GetRegistoId());
    if (await _paragemService.IsParagemOnGoingAsync(registoId))
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { started = false, message = "Já existe uma paragem a decorrer..." });
    }
    else
    {
        await _paragemService.RegistarInicioParagemAsync(paragemId, paragem, registoId);
        _registoService.UpdateParagem(new ProducaoRegisto(registoId)
        {
            IsParado = true
        });

        await _registoService.SaveChangesAsync();
        _cache.Set(CustomCacheEntries.RecordIsParado, true, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(8));

        return new JsonResult(new { started = true, message = "Paragem Iniciada." });
    }
}
```

here i only check first if the user account is blocked in the database first without checking cache first and then create the cache entry.

Every user will be locked because of this.

So my point is... Is there a way to achieve this like tag helpers?

Comment: Why not use the username/user ID as the key for the cache? Then you can store whatever you need to under the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CacheTagHelper` is different than cache in general. It works via the request and therefore can vary on things like headers or cookie values. Just using `MemoryCache` or `IDistributedCache` directly is low-level; you're just adding values for keys directly, so there's nothing here to "vary" on.

That said, you can compose your key using something like the authenticated user's id, which would then give each user a unique entry in the cache, i.e. something like:

```
var cacheKey = $"myawesomecachekey-{User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)}";
```

Short of that, you should use session storage, which is automatically unique to the user, because it's per *session*.

Comment: Session storage has a lot of caveats in dot net core (one of which I've spent the last 2 days debugging).  In short, you can end up in a race condition where a session value isn't updated properly.  See this link for more information, where it's clear that the recommendation is *not* to store live objects in session: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18159

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives to the cache. For details please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that describes them in greater detail.

### Session State

An alternative would be to store the value in session state. This way, the session of one user does not interfere with the ones of others.

However, there are some downsides of this approach. If the session state is kept in memory, you cannot run your application in a server farm because one server does not know of the others session memory. So you would need to save the session state in a cache (REDIS?) or a  database.

In addition, as session memory is stored in the server users cannot change it and avoid the redirection that you try to implement. The downside is that this reduces the amount of users that your server can handle because the server needs to have a specific amount of memory per user.

### Cookies

You can send a cookie to the client and check for this cookie when the next request arrives at your server. The downside of this approach is that the user can delete the cookie. If the only consequence of a missing cookie is a request to the database, this is neglectable.

You can use session cookies that are discarded by the server when the session expires.

### General

Another hint is that you need to clear the state memory when a user signs out so that with the next sign in, the state is correctly set up for the new user.